# What will `systemctl is-active ...` return if failed?

Tags: systemd

If I execute `systemctl is-active <service-name>`, what will be the value of result code when service was active but it failed? `0` (success) or another?

Comment: Hello. You say such as? What is an actual question so you can be given an actual answer.

Comment: Why not try it?

Comment: The man page under `is-active` isn't very illuminating, but under `reset-failed` it says *"When a unit fails in some way (i.e. process exiting with non-zero error code, terminating abnormally or timing out), it will automatically enter the "failed" state and its exit code and status is recorded for introspection by the administrator until the service is stopped/re-started or reset with this command."* suggesting that the exit status of the unit itself should be inherited from whatever sub-process failed. I wonder how one could test that?

Comment: @steeldrive That's the thing. I was not up to force the program to crash manually in order to check. But I trust my command should return non-0 then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so based on a recent failure on my auto-restart script it seems `systemctl --quiet is-active <service-name>` returned `0`, which makes sense in a way with the obtained `active(failed)` detailed output I remember from an older failure case.

Solution is probably to check for [is-failed](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemctl.1.html) instead, given that I don't have the need to auto-restart my service in case it was explicitly stopped (to what the original command shall return non-`0` and its detailed output contain `inactive`, naturally), and given I want it to be restarted when **failed**.

Comment: maybe it is worth mentioning that the return of "active" is treated as "True" (inactive = False) when it comes to using that boolean value in a pipe. `systemctl --is-active mysql.server && systemctl stop mysql.service` i.e. will stop the mysql service if it is running.

Answer (score 1):

if failed then status is "inactive". I reproduced it if I understood correctly your question:

```
brad@zika:~$ systemctl is-active fwupd-refresh
inactive
brad@zika:~$ systemctl status fwupd-refresh
○ fwupd-refresh.service - Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fwupd-refresh.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2022-04-27 08:00:12 EDT; 2h 51min ago
TriggeredBy: ● fwupd-refresh.timer
       Docs: man:fwupdmgr(1)
    Process: 1899748 ExecStart=/usr/bin/fwupdmgr refresh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1899748 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 262ms

Apr 27 08:00:06 zika.gattaca.net systemd[1]: Starting Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd...
Apr 27 08:00:12 zika.gattaca.net systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 27 08:00:12 zika.gattaca.net systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 27 08:00:12 zika.gattaca.net systemd[1]: Failed to start Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
brad@zika:~$
```

Comment: To replicate my failure state you should see `active(failed)`, which is what I got. Appart from this, yours isn't the kind of output I'm interested in, because that returns the full human readable status, unlike a result code (which I wanted to check instead for efficiency and good practice). To obtain the result codes, you might check it with `$?`.

Comment: Anyway, the service finally failed itself again (per my client report) and just found out `is-active` presumably returned `0`, contrary to what I expected, so that my script couldn't restart it afterwards (yes, there is a script involved which restarts the service when such return code is `non-0`). Waiting for my edited script that instead checks for `is-failed` and reverses the result code check to see if it solves my demand.